# looking for a replace() wildcard for numbers

Tags: c#, replace

I not an expert in C# i've only been doing it for a few months.

I have a token `@Html.Raw(Model.Prices.SitePrice.Text)` that displays a price for a product ($9.99)

I needed to remove the $ sign from the token so i put `@Html.Raw(Model.Prices.SitePrice.Text.Replace("$", ""))`

This all works fine, The issue is when I apply a special /promotion to that product, it changes the token to display:

`<strike>$9.99</strike> $7.99` it should display `7.99` once working.

I want the `<stike>$##.##</strike>` removed using a wildcard to deal with any number between the strike.

What would be the best way of writing the .replace() for this this text? (has to be inline for google schema data)

Ive tried:

`@Html.Raw(Model.Prices.SitePrice.Text.Replace("$", "").Replace("<strike>[\r\n]+</strike> ", ""))`

`@Html.Raw(Model.Prices.SitePrice.Text.Replace("$", "").Replace("<strike>(.*)</strike> ", ""))`

7 different vaules?

`<strike>$9.99</strike> $7.99` it should display `7.99`

`<strike>$10.99</strike> $8.99` it should display `8.99`

`<strike>$199.00</strike> $188.00` it should display `188.00`

`<strike>$20.00</strike> $18.50` it should display `18.50`

`<strike>$4.20</strike> $2.20` it should display `2.20`

`<strike>$12345.00</strike> $12225.00` it should display `12225.00`

Comment: What I personally would do is `Reverse` the string, then `TakeWhile` while the character is not `$` and then `Reverse` it again (or use `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` to avoid the need for the `Reverse`s). This will basically get everything from the end of the string **after** the last $ sign.

Comment: Surely you should have "Price" and "DiscountedPrice" (or something to this effect) as individual fields in your database (as an actual currency/decimal type), rather than storing it as text? Perhaps there's some reason why you can't, but to me it seems that it would be a better way to do things.

Comment: sadly im using something called Hotcakes ecommerce and its very dodgy. it only has one reference for both price & discounted price. very annoying.

Comment: is it just not possible with replace? and just trying to do what you have mentioned, I just need to figure out how to write it :P

Comment: Sure, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(Model.Prices.SitePrice.Text, @"<strike>[\s\S]*</strike>", "").Trim().TrimStart('$'))
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, Appriciate the help!
This erros due too `The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Should be able to work with what you've given me. thank you

Comment: prefix `Regex` with `System.Text.RegularExpressions.` would work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Littlery just needed this for google schema code. works like a charm & have learnt lots. Where do i send the box of beer?

Comment: Aha, the funny words were the box of beer already, though it was removed :-<

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking for that comment. I'l add it back in the question for you!

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider:

```
@Html.Raw(new string(Model.Prices.SitePrice.Text.Reverse().TakeWhile(z => z != '$').Reverse().ToArray()))
```

This will take the text at the end of the `SitePrice` up until (and not including) the $.

`Reverse` means it reverses the string. `TakeWhile` gets you the text up until the `$`. `Reverse` reverses it back again. `new string` converts the char array back to a string.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was testing with .Reverse but was breaking the value. 
I tried your way and this works as well, just couldnt wrap my head around what you meant earlyer. 

Thanks for your example, helps me understand how a few things work.